# Calling C++ From JMS with JNI

Tags: java, c++, jakarta-ee, java-native-interface, jms

I'm trying to call Sleuth Kit C++ Framework through its JNI wrapper from a JMS MessageListener. But I'm getting this error

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/libtsk_jni.so: libtsk.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I tried coping the libtsk_jni.so to /tmp but no difference. 
But I can do this in a Java console application. What could be the error?

```
public void onMessage(Message message) {
   try {
      String imagePath = "uploads/Cfreds001A001.dd";
         try{
            SleuthkitCase sk = SleuthkitCase.newCase(imagePath + ".db");

         } catch (TskCoreException ex) {

         } 
  } catch (JMSException ex) {
     Logger.getLogger(WorkerBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
     Logger.getLogger(WorkerBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Comment: Where is the `libtsk.so.10` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attempting to use native methods from code running in a Java EE container is not allowed by the standard and may cause undefined behavior.  See the JavaWorld article from August 2000 ["Programming restrictions on EJB"](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076155/java-web-development/programming-restrictions-on-ejb.html), still true today as far as I know.

Depending on your Java EE container, you may in fact be able to get this to work.  It may help to put the `libtsk_jni.so` in the system library directory or to edit the server's start script to set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.

Comment: +1 for the advice :) , Then what is the standard way I can run Sleuth Kit or any c++ code from Java EE. I'm sure, I'm not the only one who want to do something like this. O:) Aren't Image processing libraries use native codes like Sleuth Kit? :) Somehow, there should be a way, right? :)

Comment: Run Sleuth Kit in a separate process. You could create that process each time with [Runtime.exec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[])), or it could be long-running (even on a different host) and accepting commands on a TCP socket, and the onMessage method would use [Socket](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#Socket(java.lang.String,%20int)) to connect to it; or you could run it ina database that supports Java or C stored procedures (DB2, Oracle, Postgres...) and connect via JDBC (stored in JNDI).